# How to configure ip in session setting of connectable node in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: ip-address, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am currently trying to specify connectable node by setting session in Apache IoTDB. I checked the official guide and seems like users can configure one ip and multiple ip in session. May I ask, is there a difference between the two choices here if I do not have specific preference? Or can I configure one ip, and other session's ip will be handled automatically by IoTDB?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZ8fp.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference putting only one ip or multiple ips when setting `nodeUrls` in Apache IoTDB. You can just input one ip here to speed up loading code and see if there is error reported.